# DELIMITADOR PYTHON

Tags: python, csv, pandas, txt

Como faço para ler um arquivo que contém dados separados por ponto e virgula aparecer na tabela em pyhton?

Inicialmente tenho dois aquivos txt, estou utilizando a biblioteca pandas ai preciso gerar um terceito txt e colocar esses dois arquivos juntos em uma unica tabela

exemplo dos dados nas tabelas:
4;1000 ;1000 ;0 ;0 ;1000 ;00000;00000;00003;0.00 ;0

```
import pandas as pd

df_bonus = pd.read_csv('bonus.txt')
df_bonus

df_clientes = pd.read_csv('clientes.txt')
df_clientes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método read_csv() suporta um parâmetro com o delimitador.

```
df_bonus = pd.read_csv('bonus.txt', delimiter=';')
```